# Incompatible types when assigning to type 't_result' from type 'int', why?

Tags: c, struct, math.h

I really don't understand why I get this error.

```
architect.c: In function ‘main’:
architect.c:91:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_result’ from type ‘int’
architect.c:93:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_result’ from type ‘int’
architect.c:95:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_result’ from type ‘int’
architect.c:97:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_result’ from type ‘int’
architect.c:99:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘t_result’ from type ‘int’
```

This is my code :

```
    if (av[j][i] == 'R')
    {
        printf("rotation d'angle %s degrés\n", av[j + 1]);
        if (av[j - 3][i] == 'T')
91          s_rota = my_rota(s_trans.result1, s_trans.result2, atoi(av[j + 1]));
        else if (av[j - 3][i] == 'H')
93          s_rota = my_rota(s_homot.result1, s_homot.result2, atoi(av[j + 1]));
        else if (av[j - 2][i] == 'S')
95          s_rota = my_rota(s_sym.result1, s_sym.result2, atoi(av[j + 1]));
        else if (av[j - 2][i] == 'R')
97          s_rota = my_rota(s_rota.result1, s_rota.result2, atoi(av[j + 1]));
        else
99          s_rota = my_rota(atoi(av[j - 2]), atoi(av[j - 1]), atoi(av [j + 1]));
        printf("(%s,%s) => (%d,%d)\n", av[j - 2], av[j - 1], s_rota.result1, s_rota.result2);
    }
```

This is my second function :

```
t_result my_rotation(int x, int y, int degree)
{
    t_result s_rota;

    s_rota.result1 = (cos(degree) * x) - (sin(degree) * y);
    s_rota.result2 = (sin(degree) * x) + (cos(degree) * y);
    return (s_rota);
}
```

And this is my header:

```
#ifndef _STRUCT_H_
#define _STRUCT_H_

typedef struct s_result
{
    int   result1;
    int   result2;
}   t_result;

#endif /*  _STRUCT_H_ */
```

Also, I have some problem with `cos` and `sin` (and I didn't forget my include).

Comment: "my_rota" does not sound much like "my_rotation".  Keep your code clean.

Comment: You have "some problem" with `cos` and `sin`? Shall we guess what the problem is?

Comment: You aren't compiling with enough warnings enabled, so you don't know when the compiler is having to guess what the return type of a function is.  You should start with `-Wall`; I use `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` and I expect my code to compile.  The absence of such warnings probably accounts for the problems with `cos` and `sin` (or, in other words, you're living in a state of `sin` because you don't have the warnings enabled).

Comment: Note that `cos()` and `sin()` expect the argument in radians, not degrees. You will need to divide the input by `pi / 180` (where pi is not the name you'll use; you might be able to use M_PI, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:** @Hans is pointing out the basic problem, that you're defining `my_rotation` while trying to invoke `my_rota`. You shall fix this first.

---

Seems caused by [implicit function declarations](https://www.google.com/search?q=implicit+function+declaration). Have you declared the function `my_rotation` before line 95?

You could try adding this line to your header:

```
extern t_result my_rotation(int x, int y, int degree);
```

Comment: Also make sure that `#include <math.h>` precedes the use of `cos` and `sin` too.